# How to show a function has a global maximum without using derivatives

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization

I want to show that $f(x) = |x|e^{-|x|}$ has a global maximum for some $x>0$. I don't want to use derivatives to do this. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant properties of $f$ are that $f$ is a continuous, non-negative function on $[0,\infty)$ with $f(0) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$.

To prove that $f$ is bounded, first argue that there exists an $X > 0$ such that $f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x > X$.  Moreover, since $f$ is continuous on the compact set $[0,X]$, $f$ is bounded on $[0,X]$, say $f(x) \leq m$ for some $m > 0$.

Thus $f$ is bounded, so let $M = \text{sup}_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x)$.  We can find $X' > 0$ such that $f(x) \leq M/2$ for all $x > X'$.  It follows that $\text{sup}_{0 \leq x \leq X'} f(x) = M$, so $f(x) = M$ for some $x$ in $[0,X']$, i.e. $f$ achieves a global maximum value.

Comment: how can I argue that such an $X$ exists? (first part)

Comment: Such an $X$ exists because $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$.  (You can make $f(x) \leq$ any upper bound you want; I chose $1$ for convenience.)

Comment: This makes sense, I just dont trust myself to come up with something like this on my own :)

I'm finding it difficult to argue such a thing without derivatives!

Comment: can you explain why you chose $M/2$ for an upper bound on f in the second part?

Comment: The choice of $M/2$ is to create an interval $[0,X']$ where we know the supremum is the same as the supremum over all of $[0,\infty)$.  (You could choose any value $M - \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.)  Once the supremum is located in a compact domain (= closed interval here), you can use the key theorem that the supremum of a continuous function on a compact set is actually attained, which means that you have a global maximum.

Answer (score 1):

well since $x>0$, you have $f(x)=xe^{-x}$, you need to show this function is concave. $f(x)$ is log-concave:
$\log f(x)=\log(x)-x$ (since $log(x)$ is concave and $-x$ is affine),

Therefore $log(f(x))$ has a unique maximum, since $log$ is a monotone function, you can conclude $f(x)$ has a global maximum.